# Reading json data from battlelog.battlefield.com

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to jquery and working with json, so please bear with me.  This requires you to log into http://battlelog.battlefield.com, but once you're there you should be able to access the following page.

I'm using code like below, but it seems to fail:

```
$.getJSON('http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/overviewPopulateStats/280966984/bf3-us-assault/1/', function(t) {
    alert('test');
});
```

It looks like valid json, if I go to the url in my browser and copy and paste it to a site like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ it doesn't have a problem reading it.

My question is, is there anyway I can read this json data with jquery?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make Ajax requests to domains that are not the same as the one the JavaScript code is running on (see [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for more information).

*If* the target site allows [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requests, you can use that to get around the issue. Otherwise you will not be able to load the JSON directly via jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize JSONP had to be allowed on the server, that makes sense.  Really appreciate the info, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason why that isn't working is because JQuery cannot find the cookie file related to our authentication. You'll need to use a script that first logs you in then you can try to read the data.

Here's a PHP based API that does just that:
http://www.blakeharley.com/2011/10/battlelogapi-v1-3/

Using the above API to log into Battlelog, you can also get weapon, award and vehical stats all returned in JSON:
http://www.bfclanwars.com/2011/10/25/bf3-stats-paths-json-format/

Artax

Answer (score 0):

I used this, to get the server status:

```
$.post("http://api.bf3stats.com/pc/server/", {
       'id': "the-server-id"
    }, function(data) {
        var serverData = $.parseJSON(data);
});
```